# Selenium throwing exception when a modal dialog is shown at start of ie instance

Tags: selenium, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

I have to automate a scenario where a modal dialog opens immediately after ie is open i.e.

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver=webdriver.Ie()
```

Once i do this, IE instance opens and an IE modal dialog opens on top of ie.

Now selenium closes this modal dialog immediately and throws an exception:

> Unexpected alert present, Modal Dialog present.

But i have to handle this modal dialog.

Is there any way to handle this dialog and make sure selenium does not throw exception and quit?

Comment: How do other browsers behave in such a situation?

Comment: What is the modal dialog that is opening?

Comment: @JimEvans Same here, the alert is "Internet Explorer is not currently you default browser.......".

Comment: @CodeEnthusiastic: Manually set your IE to not check default browser again.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem, selenium dismissing the alert (as if Cancel was clicked), where you want to confirm (as if OK was clicked).
For me it worked to initialize the driver by initializing webdriver with the UnexpectedAlertBehavior option, as per below

```
private static InternetExplorerOptions internetExplorerOptions = new InternetExplorerOptions{ UnexpectedAlertBehavior = InternetExplorerUnexpectedAlertBehavior.Accept };

public static InternetExplorerDriver Driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(SeleniumLocator.GetSeleniumDriverPath(), internetExplorerOptions);
```